# How to convert textbox and label to strings properly

Tags: c#-2.0

I have this code

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("Scores.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.Write("Name: " + name_box.Text + " Time " + label1.Text);
        sw.Close();
```

which is simple the label1 is assgined to a Timer tick as in the folowing

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Format and display the TimeSpan value. 
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
       label1.Text = elapsedTime;
    }
```

now when I open the Text File I found the following results

```
Name: Tony Time 00:00:06.67Text:  Time [System.Windows.Forms.Timer], Interval: 100
```

which are perfect but what is ( Text:  Time [System.Windows.Forms.Timer], Interval: 100)
I don't want that to appear in the txt

thanx in advance

Comment: it looks a lot like the output you would get from timer1.ToString. Are you sure there's not a mistake like that somewhere?

Comment: `StreamWriter` is not writing extra stuff. You are sending it stuff that you don't want it to write. I am editing your title to reflect this.

Comment: @Jason: Actually you're both wrong. ;)  The problem isn't that extra stuff is being sent, the problem was that the extra stuff is *already in the file*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` in the constructor.  This does not erase the previous contents of the file.  I suspect that if you delete the file and then try running your program again, you won't see any of that extra stuff.

I suggest either using `FileMode.Create` or `FileMode.Append`.  Use the first if you want to overwrite the results, the second if you want to... well, append.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the following line somewhere else in your code:

```
label1.Text = timer1.ToString();
```

You should write-click the word `label1` in your code, then click Find All References to see what else you're doing with it.

---

By the way, instead of creating a stream, you should use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx), like this:

```
File.WriteAllText("Scores.txt", "Name: " + name_box.Text + " Time " + label1.Text);
```

Comment: Im Sure I don't have (label1.Text = timer1.ToString();)

Comment: @Tony: are you really, really, really sure? Just ran your code and it works as is.